# History of the notation for scalar product

Tags: linear-algebra, ho.history-overview

What's the history of the development of the notation for (real or hermitian) scalar product? In particular,

Did "bra-ket" notations, such as $\langle u\mid v\rangle$ or $(u\mid v)$, first arise with Paul Dirac in the context of quantum mechanics?

Did the $\langle u, v\rangle$ notation appear later as a modification of the one with the vertical bar or vice versa?

Was the "dot product" notation $\overrightarrow{u}\bullet\overrightarrow{u}$ introduced before the "bra-ket" ones?

Comment: Yes, the bra-ket was introduced by Dirac and made standard in his celebrated book on QM . However, looks like Grassman had a similar notation long before that ( [ v, w] rather than <v, w>

Comment: Except that the purpose of Dirac's notation was to *separate* the two vectors in the notation.  Apparently he went round saying "I invented the bra" (see the depressing biography "The Strangest Man" by Graham Farmelo).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cajori, *A History of Mathematical Notation* § 506 (vol 2) attributes to Grassmann the notations $a \times b$ (1848) and $[a|b]$ (1862) for the scalar product, to Heaviside and others the $a|b$ in the 1890s, to Lorentz $(a,b)$ in the early 1900s.

Comment: Isn't the historical spelling "Grassmann"?

Comment: Yes. I am guilty of the same typo: Grassmann, ie Graßmann

Comment: Of course, thank you